# org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction @scheduled

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am using scheduled task to update my database like this:

```
    public interface UserRatingManager {
        public void updateAllUsers();
    }

    @Service
    public class DefaultUserRatingManager implements UserRatingManager {

        @Autowired
        UserRatingDAO userRatingDAO;

            @Override
        @Transactional("txName")
        public void updateAllUsers() {
            List<String> userIds = userRatingDAO.getAllUserIds();
            for (String userId : userIds) {
                updateUserRating(userId);
            }
        }
    }

public interface UserRatingDAO extends GenericDAO<UserRating, String> {
    public void deleteAll();
    public List<String> getAllUserIds();
}

@Repository
public class HibernateUserRatingDAO extends BaseDAO<UserRating, String> implements UserRatingDAO {

    @Override
    public List<String> getAllUserIds() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Query q1 = getSession().createQuery("Select userId from UserRating");
    }
}
```

I configured the persistence like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.estartup" })
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void run() {
        userRatingManager().updateAllUsers();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(env.getProperty("connection.url"), env.getProperty("connection.username"), env.getProperty("connection.password"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    public PersistenceConfig() {
        super();
    }


    @Bean
    public UserRatingUpdate userRatingUpdate() {
        return new UserRatingUpdate();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserRatingManager userRatingManager() {
        return new DefaultUserRatingManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean runnableSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = null;
        try {
            factoryBean = createBaseSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return factoryBean;
    }


    private LocalSessionFactoryBean createBaseSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean;
        factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties pp = new Properties();
        pp.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        pp.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", "3");
        pp.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.estartup.*" });
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(pp);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "txName")
    public HibernateTransactionManager runnableTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager(runnableSessionFactory().getObject());
        return htm;
    }
}
```

However, when I get to:

```
Query q1 = getSession().createQuery("Select userId from UserRating");
```

in the above `HibernateUserRatingDAO` I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.estartup.dao.impl.HibernateUserRatingDAO.getAllUserIds(HibernateUserRatingDAO.java:36)
```

How can I configure to include my scheduled tasks in transactions ?

**EDITED:**

Here is the code for `BaseDAO`

```
@Repository
public class BaseDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericDAOImpl<T, ID> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    public void setTopAndForUpdate(int top, Query query){
        query.setLockOptions(LockOptions.UPGRADE);
        query.setFirstResult(0);
        query.setMaxResults(top);
    }
```

**EDITED**

Enabling Spring transaction prints the following log:

```
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-1] org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'updateAllUsers' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'txName'
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have the scheduled method inside the configuration. Why don't you try creating a new Spring service that will have `UserRatingUpdate` as a dependency and use `@Scheduled` on a method of that new class

Comment: I took it from their documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html they show a way to declare @schedule in configuration

Comment: True, but as I explain in my answer that work well when need to use a proxy for one of the dependencies

Comment: Could you please also post the code for `BaseDAO`?

Comment: @geoand I just posted it

Comment: Can you humour me and check if your session that you get back from `getSession()` is null or not. Also where is your `getSession()` method?

Comment: Can you enable DEBUG logging in your project and test again? After testing, provide the complete log (probably, via [http://pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/). I have used your exact code (minus `UserRatingUpdate` and `updateUserRating(userId);` because I don't know what they do and used H2 instead of MySQL) in a standalone simple project and it works for me. I can see the transactions being created and committed and I have no errors.

Comment: @JamesMassey it's not null. I get it from a class called HibernateBaseDAO https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/source/browse/trunk/trg-dao-hibernate/src/main/java/com/googlecode/genericdao/dao/hibernate/HibernateBaseDAO.java?r=627 it's part of the open source

Comment: @AndreiStefan what do you mean by putting it in DEBUG logging mode? I am using LOGBACK

Comment: I mean enabling more messages to be produced in logs. Many transactions related logging messages in Spring are displayed when DEBUG is set as logging level.

Comment: @JamesMassey in inspect the getSession returns org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper@2f314800

Comment: @AndreiStefan I edited my answer with the log

Comment: Ok, that shows the method is registered as a transactional method. Can you post the complete log file that should show what's going on when the method is actually called?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I don't suppose you can share you code on Github, can you?

Comment: @geoand, I already did. See my answer.

Comment: Can you post any additional configuration files you might have? I suspect that there is a `hibernate.properties` and/or `hibernate.cfg.xml` file somewhere. Also what would help is to enable debug (or trace) logging and see what and how hibernate is configured.

Comment: @Dejel I am sure if you have already mentioned somewhere in the comments, but do you have your code on GitHub or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already mentioned, I used your code and created a [small sample](https://github.com/astefan-pivotal/scheduled_transactions) that works for me. Judging by the classes used, I assumed you are using [Hibernate Generic DAO Framework](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/). It's a standalone sample, the `main()` class is Main. Running it you can see the transactional related DEBUG messages in logs that show when a transaction is initiated and committed. You can compare my settings, jars versions used with what you have and see if anything stands out.

Also, as I already suggested you might want to look in the logs to see if proper transactional behavior is being used and compare that with the logs my sample creates.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening in this case is that since you are using `userRatingManager()` inside the configuration (where the actual scheduled method exists), the proxy that Spring creates to handle the transaction management for `UserRatingUpdate` is not being used.

I propose you do the following:

```
public interface WhateverService {

   void executeScheduled();
}

@Service
public class WhateverServiceImpl {

   private final UserRatingManager userRatingManager;

   @Autowired
   public WhateverServiceImpl(UserRatingManager userRatingManager) {
      this.userRatingManager = userRatingManager;
   }

   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
   public void executeScheduled() {
      userRatingManager.updateAllUsers()
   }
}
```

Also change your transaction manager configuration code to:

```
    @Bean(name = "txName")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager runnableTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return htm;
    }
```

and remove `factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();` from `createBaseSessionFactory`

Comment: Thanks I tried it, I see that the task is being scheduled but it doesn't work - I get the same error

Comment: htm.setSessionFactory(runnableSessionFactory()); cannot be compiled. Shall I cast it to (SessionFactory) as it suggests?

Comment: I made a mistake earlier, sorry about that. Check the updated code

Comment: Damn... Could you also post the code for `BaseDao`?

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look!

Comment: Try adding `pp.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext")` to Hibernate configuration and let me know what happens. If it works I'll add it to the answer. If not, we'll have to keep looking :)

Comment: Ok, does the code work when you called in a non-scheduled context?

Comment: I am using it in REST call and there I open my own session not via transactional

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate your problem so I integrated it in my Hibernate examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/vladmihalcea.wordpress.com/tree/master/hibernate-facts/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/scheduler):

You can run my CompanySchedulerTest and see it's working so this is what I did to run it:

1. I made sure the application context is aware of our scheduler

   ```
   <task:annotation-driven/>
   ```
2. The scheduler is defined in its own bean:

   ```
   @Service
   public class CompanyScheduler implements DisposableBean {

   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompanyScheduler.class);

   @Autowired
   private CompanyManager companyManager;

   private volatile boolean enabled = true;

   @Override
   public void destroy() throws Exception {
       enabled = false;
   }

   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 100)
   public void run() {
       if (enabled) {
           LOG.info("Run scheduler");
           companyManager.updateAllUsers();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
3. My JPA/Hibernate configs are in applicationContext-test.xml and they are configured for JPA according to the Spring framework indications, so you might want to double check your Hibernate settings as well.

Comment: Hi! regarding I made sure the application context is aware of our scheduler - if I use @configuration class do I still need it?

Comment: Since [Spring 3.1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7420) there is support for setting the scheduler setting through java based config.